# How to disable "Trending on Google+" posts?

Tags: google-plus

Is there a way to disable the "Trending on Google+" post from appearing on my feed?

The only help I could find is https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1686118?hl=en and is for the old ("classic") Google+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On https://plus.google.com/settings, look for the following setting in the "stream" section.

> Amount of Trending & Recommended posts to show in stream

[image]